# Run C# executable from command line and specify path to libraries needed

Tags: c#, mono

I am running a C# executable which was built with a reference to a .Net library. The .NetLibrary is a wrapper around a C++ library, which resides in another folder (separate folder from the .NetLibrary).

The C++ library is in /usr/local bin
The .Net library is in /projects/csharp/NetWrapperProj/bin/Debug
The executable is in /projects/csharp/testharness/bin/Debug

As you may have guessed from the paths, I am running .Net using mono on Linux (Ubuntu 10.0.4).
mono version 2.10.

How may I specify the required binaries to the executable - to avoid Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException type exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Why do you have a library in `/usr/local/bin`? This is not a place the loader will look for it. Put it somewhere inside `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the DLLs/Libraries need to be in the same directory as the executable. From the [Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/DllNotFoundException):

> If a library location has not been explicitly specified in a DllMap
>   entry in an application or assembly .config file, Mono will search for
>   a library in a few places:
>
> - The directory where the referencing image was loaded from.
> - In any place the system's dynamic loader is configured to look
>     for shared libraries. For  example on Linux this is specified in the
>     $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and the /etc/ld.so.conf file. On
>     windows the $PATH environment variable is used, instead.

You can read more at the Mono website on how to remedy this problem.